# Determine selected photos in AGImagePickerController 

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using `AGImagePickerController`. Im having a hard time figuring out how to import the images selected into my `iCarousel` which is in another carousel. I know that the `success block` in it contains the selected image. I can't seem to import it in my `awakeFromNib` or putting it in an array.

here is my code that calls the AGImagePickerController:

```
 -(IBAction) cameraRoll {AGImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[AGImagePickerController alloc] initWithFailureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"User has cancelled.");
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        } else
        {     
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

            // Wait for the view controller to show first and hide it after that
            double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            });
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];

    } andSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *info) {
        NSLog(@"Info: %@", info);
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
    }];

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
    [imagePickerController release];
}
```

In my awakeFromNib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{    
    if (self) {

        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"111.jpg",
                       @"112.jpg",
                       @"113.jpg",
                       @"114.jpg",
                       @"115.jpg",
                       @"116.jpg",
                       @"117.jpg",
                       @"118.png",
                       @"119.jpg",
                       @"120.jpg",
                       nil];

    }
}
```

Then I implement this for my carousel :

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    //create a numbered view
    UIView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to look at the contents of the `info array` using your NSLog statement. It would have been helpful to see the contents of that log statement.

I found this [here](http://pastebin.com/B2bX2i1r) and it might work:

```
for (i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
     UIImage * image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
}
```

**Edit**:

You need to save the images (either in memory or by writing them to files) after the user selects them. If you want to write them to files, you can do that like so:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

If the AGImagePickerController code is in your `iCarousel` class, you can just add the images to your `images` array. Your `successBlock` would look something like this:

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray new];

for (i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
     UIImage * image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
     [self.images addObject:image];
}
```

And finally, in your iCarousel code you need to read the images either from your images array or from the disk (depending on where you chose to save them). If you are saving them in memory 
your code could look like this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.images objectAtIndex:index]];
}
```

Or, if you decided to save the images to disk then you could recreate the UIImage objects using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];`.

Comment: Am I going to put it into the awakeFromNib of my iCarousel?

Comment: this code goes into the successBlock of the code you provided. without seeing your iCarousel code I can't help you with much else.

Comment: what is `jpgPath` and my iCarousel is in a different class so the `info` is "undeclared identifier". what to do?

Comment: I was able to save it in the path. But it was not a image. when I rename it with .png. it only display 1 image. help please

Comment: Hi i was able to save it. But I don't know how to load from NSDocumentDirectory

Comment: you need to use [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath] to load the image, as I specified in my response.

Comment: yes sir i have done that. but no images from my carousel. look at these post this is mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792873/nsdocumentdirectory-loading-images

Comment: I responded to that question and I believe my response should work for you.