# NSDocumentDirectory loading images

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I was able to save my array of files in my `NSDocumentDirectory`.
Here is what I used:

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]];
         ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
        //NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

My problem is how to load images with this format`@"Images%d.png"` into this code:

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
```

.m

```
    self.images = ??????
```

Comment: basically u want to convert your image into png from jpg??

Comment: no I want to load it in the awakeFromNib.

Comment: use count variable whose intial value is 0 So it would be NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", count]], after saving im age count would be count++; every time you would get new count

Comment: I already put them in a for statement. I mean how to implement it in the awakeFromnib? or in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to read the image names from bundle. Please modify bundle path to documents directory path. Code snippet will give you array of sorted image names also save you from using a *for-loop* to read names.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:nil];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.png'"];
NSArray *unsortedImages = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
NSArray *sortedImages = [unsortedImages 
                     sortedArrayUsingComparator:
                     ^NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2){
                         return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:(NSString*)obj2 
                                                 options:NSNumericSearch];
                    }];
```

**Friendly advice:** Avoid storing any downloadable data/images in **NSDocumentDirectory** directory as app may get rejected. Use **NSCachesDirectory** instead. Please read this [post](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/local-file-storage-in-ios-5) and related documents on Apple's developer portal.

Cheers!!
Amar.

Comment: I mean how to store them in an array in awakeFromnib after loading?

Comment: You have all image file names with you, loop through **sortedImages** array, create **UIImage** by using **initWithContentsOfFile:** method (Generate path to the image by appending file name to NSDocumentDirectory path) and load this image instance to your **images** mutable array. Remember to initialize your mutable array before you add the images to it. This piece of code will work from any method cos its just IO operations. Do not load too many images, as you can run into memory and performance issues. Hope this helps!

Comment: Im loading it into a iCarousel. don't quite get what you are saying. can you post some sample code?

Comment: Can you please clarify to exactly what problem you are facing? If you need anything specific, please describe it in the question.

Comment: I want to load the saved images in an NSMutableArray.

Comment: This is the loop I was suggesting you. 
        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedImages count]];
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [sortedImages objectEnumerator];
    while ([enumerator nextObject]) {
    NSString *imageFileName = (NSString*) [enumerator nextObject];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageFileName];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [self.images addObject:image];
    [image release];
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11864/discussion-between-user1311817-and-amar)

Answer (score 1):

for Saving Images to `NSDocumentDirectory`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];//m_nImageIndex
        NSString *imagename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedImage%d.png",m_nImageIndex];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename];
        // Get PNG data from following method
        NSData *myData =     UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        // It is better to get JPEG data because jpeg data will store the location and other related information of image.
        [myData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
        //[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image ,1) writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

for retrieving Images

```
          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
          NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
          NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"savedImage%d.png",indexPath.row]];
          UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];

          cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a png extension as a jpg file. I believe this should work:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.jpg", i]];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

    // to load the image later:
    UIImage *imageFromDisk = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath];
```