# How to use AssetLibrary url to image?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using AGImagePickerController which is using AssetLibrary, When images are selected it returns NSArray that contains URL to image.

**My question is How can i use Array to retrieve the image?**

NSLog shows the content of returned array as follows

```
(
"ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6D1AAC7F-3580-418E-AE87-8A5C83F76EAD&ext=JPG",
"ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1322E0E0-46CD-44DF-A736-FF812694B40C&ext=JPG"
```

Do i need to explode each array index based on "-" needle?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved the problem. For sake of others here is how i did it

```
for (i = 0; i < info.count; i++) {
     ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
     UIImage * image  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
}
```

Source: [Determine selected photos in AGImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102593/determine-selected-photos-in-agimagepickercontroller)